# java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no current context in hybris 1905

Tags: java, solr, sap-commerce-cloud

Trying to solr partial update through code but while converting search query into solr query getting below exception.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no current context at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.search.context.impl.DefaultFacetSearchContextFactory.getContext(DefaultFacetSearchContextFactory.java:96) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?] at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.search.context.impl.DefaultFacetSearchContextFactory.getContext(DefaultFacetSearchContextFactory.java:1) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?] at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.search.impl.DefaultSolrQueryConverter.createSolrQuery(DefaultSolrQueryConverter.java:269) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?] at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.search.impl.DefaultSolrQueryConverter.convertSolrQuery(DefaultSolrQueryConverter.java:186) ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?] at com.msw.core.servicelayer.solr.impl.DefaultMswSolrService.writeToSolrVariant(DefaultMswSolrService.java:274) [classes/:?]

Method used to convert:

```
solrQueryConverter.convertSolrQuery(SearchQuery query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you initial create you SOLR index? One for the store (the product-solr-index) and one for the backoffice (the backoffice-solr-index). In some setups hybris don't initialcreate the SOLR index on his own. Have a look in the backoffice if the indexes was created.

Comment: Yes we have index for both.
 Backoffice and storefront
 We are able to do full indexing from the backoffice
 But when tried to update document from the code, it's not getting current context